# Tengo una Imagen en trozos como puedo distribuir esos trozos aleatoriamente.PUZLE HUECO

Tags: java, java-swing

Bueno mi duda es estoy haciendo un puzle hueco en java con swing y leo la imagen perfectamente pero como hago para que los trozos de la imagen salgan aleatorias. Por ejemplo es una imagen se divide en 9 trozos una imagen, como hago para que los trozos de la imagen se distribuyan aleatoriamente en mi tablero. Aqui muestro mi codigo.

Clase JUEGO

```
package com.dinaprise.proyecto;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import com.dinaprise.proyecto.mapeado.Mapeado;

public class Juego extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Juego frame = new Juego();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Juego() {
        this.inicializar();
    }

    private void inicializar() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        // Creo barra de menu para el mapeado
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnNewMenu = new JMenu("MAPEADO");
        menuBar.add(mnNewMenu);

        JMenuItem mntmMapaTresPorTres = new JMenuItem("3X3");
        // Agrego un listener para indicar que el mapa sera 3x3
        mntmMapaTresPorTres.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Juego.this.cargaImagen(1);

            }
        });

        mnNewMenu.add(mntmMapaTresPorTres);

        JMenuItem mntmMapaCuatroPorCuatro = new JMenuItem("4X4");
        // Agrego un listener para indicar que el mapa sera 4x4
        mntmMapaCuatroPorCuatro.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Juego.this.cargaImagen(2);

            }
        });
        mnNewMenu.add(mntmMapaCuatroPorCuatro);

        JMenuItem mntmMapaCincoPorCinco = new JMenuItem("5X5");
        // Agrego un listener para indicar que el mapa sera 5x5
        mntmMapaCincoPorCinco.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Juego.this.cargaImagen(3);

            }
        });
        mnNewMenu.add(mntmMapaCincoPorCinco);
        // agrego otro menu para iniciar el juego y detenerlo
        JMenu mnJuego = new JMenu("JUEGO");
        menuBar.add(mnJuego);

        JMenuItem mntmIniciar = new JMenuItem("INICIAR");
        mnJuego.add(mntmIniciar);

        JMenuItem mntmDetener = new JMenuItem("DETENER");
        mnJuego.add(mntmDetener);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }

    /**
     * Metodo que se usa para cargar las imagenes usando la clase MAPEADO
     * 
     * @param opcion tipo de distribucion que tendra la imagen
     */
    private void cargaImagen(int opcion) {
        if (opcion == 1) {
            Mapeado mapa = new Mapeado(3, 3);
            mapa.setVisible(true);
        } else if (opcion == 2) {
            Mapeado mapa = new Mapeado(4, 4);
            mapa.setVisible(true);
        } else if (opcion == 3) {
            Mapeado mapa = new Mapeado(5, 5);
            mapa.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Clase MAPEADO

```
   package com.dinaprise.proyecto.mapeado;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class Mapeado extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private int[][] mapa;
    private ImageIcon[][] imgCeldas;
    private JPanel jpTablero;
    JButton[] btnMapa;

    /**
     * Constructor de la clase
     * 
     * @param filas    filas para el mapeado de las imagenes en el tablero
     * @param columnas columnas para el mapeado de las imagenes en el tablero
     */
    public Mapeado(int filas, int columnas) {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 320, 340);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jpTablero = new JPanel();
        jpTablero.setLayout(new GridLayout(filas, columnas));
        contentPane.add(jpTablero, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // se pasa el número de filas/columnas seleccionado para el tablero
        this.agregarBotones(filas);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        JButton btnElegir = new JButton("Elija imagen");
        contentPane.add(btnElegir, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        btnElegir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser seleccionador = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filtro = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PNG & GIF Images", "png", "gif");
                seleccionador.setFileFilter(filtro);
                int valorDevuelto = seleccionador.showOpenDialog(Mapeado.this);
                if (valorDevuelto == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File fImagen = seleccionador.getSelectedFile();
                    setButtonImage(Mapeado.this.agregarImagen(fImagen.getAbsolutePath(), filas, columnas));
                }

            }
        });
        {

        }
    }

    /**
     * Añade los botones al tablero y al array de botones
     * 
     * @param filas Número de filas del tablero
     */
    private void agregarBotones(int filas) {
        this.btnMapa = new JButton[filas * filas];
        for (int i = 0; i < filas * filas; i++) {
            JButton btnMapea = new JButton("");
            btnMapa[i] = btnMapea;
            this.jpTablero.add(btnMapea);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Asigna un trozo de imagen a cada botón del tablero
     * 
     * @param images Array para los trozos de imagen
     */
    private void setButtonImage(BufferedImage[] images) {
        for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            btnMapa[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(images[i]));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Divide una imagen dada en trozos de un tamaño específico
     * 
     * @param rutaImagen Ruta del fichero de imagen
     * @return Array de imágenes con los trozos de la imagen cargada desde el
     *         fichero de imagen
     */
    public BufferedImage[] agregarImagen(String rutaImagen, int filas, int columnas) {
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedImage imagen = null;
        int anchoImagenCelda, altoImagenCelda, anchoImagen, altoImagen;

        int count = 0;

        BufferedImage imagenes[];

        try {

            File file = new File(rutaImagen);

            fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            imagen = ImageIO.read(fis);

        } catch (IOException e) {

            if (e instanceof FileNotFoundException)

                System.out.println("Fichero no encontrado");

            System.out.println("Error de lectura");

        }
        // Calculo del ancho y alto de la imagen
        anchoImagen = imagen.getWidth();
        altoImagen = imagen.getHeight();

        anchoImagenCelda = anchoImagen / filas;

        altoImagenCelda = altoImagen / columnas;

        this.imgCeldas = new ImageIcon[filas][columnas];
        // Inicializo array que va a contener las imagenes troceadas
        imagenes = new BufferedImage[filas * columnas];
        // Se crea el tablero de juego correcto
        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {

                imagenes[count] = imagen.getSubimage(j * anchoImagenCelda, i * altoImagenCelda, anchoImagenCelda,
                        altoImagenCelda);

                this.imgCeldas[i][j] = new ImageIcon(imagenes[count]);

                count++;
            }

        }

        return imagenes;
    }

}
```

Las imagenes las carga todas correctamente, lo unico que la imagen sale perfecta y quiero que la imagen salga donde quiera. Ejemplo un gato para la distribucion 3x3, pues que la pata trasera del gato este en la cabeza, la cabeza en la pata delantera, etc... Pienso que en el Metodo set buttonImage de la clase JUEGO se puede modificar, pero no se hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Sale ordenado por que tu metodo "agregarImagen" lo hace así.

Justo antes de devolver las imágenes, deberías de aplicar un random de coordenadas para realizar permutas de imágenes.

En este ejemplo voy a permutar 10 fragmentos aleatorios( puede que un mismo fragmento cambie de lugar dos veces)

```
int sizeGrid=3;//imagen 3 fragmentos x 3 fragmentos
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  int ranXOri = (int )(Math. random() * sizeGrid+1)
  int ranYOri = (int )(Math. random() * sizeGrid+1)
  int ranXDes = (int )(Math. random() * sizeGrid+1)
  int ranYDes = (int )(Math. random() * sizeGrid+1)

  ImageIcon aux = this.imgCeldas[ranXOri][ranYOri];
  this.imgCeldas[ranXDes][ranYDes]=this.imgCeldas[ranXOri][ranYOri];
  this.imgCeldas[ranXOri][ranYOri]=aux;

}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero lo unico que hice fue donde pone  imagenes[count] = imagen.getSubimage(j * anchoImagenCelda, i * altoImagenCelda, anchoImagenCelda,
                        altoImagenCelda);
cambie el j*anchoImagenCelda por i*altoImagenCelda y donde pone i*altoImagenCelda por j*anchoImagenCelda pero gracias por la ayuda, aunque realmente no aleatoriza la imagen sino que posiciona los cuadrados en otros lugares, pero siempre igual.